# I just want to confirm my thoughts regarding this op-amp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier

I was constructing a circuit which contains an operational amplifier designed to be controlled by a digital signal (5V HIGH, 0V LOW).

My intented design was: upon receiving a 5V signal, the amplifier should function as a non-inverting amplifier with a gain of 1+(Rf/R1); receiving a 0V signal should remove the gain.

A kind user suggested me this circuit design involving an analogue switch in series with resistor R1 (on when receiving 5V, off when 0V):

[image: I did not design this]

I need someone to verify my understanding regarding this circuit: The op-amp behaves like a typical non-inverting amplifier with gain 1+(Rf/R1). Upon sending a 0V signal to the switch, the R1 is disconnected from the circuit. This consequently turns the gain to 1, i.e. the op-amp behaves like a voltage follower.

Is my understanding of this circuit correct?

Comment: An alternative single opamp circuit involves a double-throw switch (SPDT), found in: https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/synchronous-detectors-facilitate-precision.html    figure 4

Comment: You need to better define the "control" you want. This circuit will switch between 2 different gains, one currently set to 1, as you said. If you wanted to enable/disable the signal, you need something different.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. When the switch is open the gain is 1 and when it is closed it is 1+(Rf/Rin). There are details in the switch, signal levels, and supply rails that affect the implementation, but your basic premise is right.

Comment: @BrianDrummond if I only wanted to turn off the amplification for Vin (i.e. retain the original signal), then this is sufficient right?